# How to programatically change file user owner

Tags: 7, files, services

I'm using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module. I can upload files through web services, but the problem is that all the created files have the same owner, the user account used for the web services. I would like to change this user, but I don't know how to do it.

I have been looking for the functions defined in the [file.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/7) file, but I haven't found a function to change this. How could I change the file's owner?

Comment: Did you try just passing the `uid` along during the `POST` to `?q=my-endpoint/file.json`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did it. But after I saw that nothing changed I inspected file_save_data function (file.inc) and I saw that this function has file->uid = $user->uid, that is, the user that is logged in. And then, it ignores the uid I pass.

Comment: If `file.inc` has the user id hard coded in, then I think the only way around it is patching the `file.inc` module to listen for your `POST` user id.

Comment: Actually, check out `hook_entity_presave()`, you can probably use that to set the `uid` on the file to data available in the `$_POST` array: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a module built to handle this, but you could build something easily enough to do it:

- the DB table file_managed handles files, and includes a uid field which is the user ID of the file 'owner'

This could be modified in a custom module, but a **MAJOR WARNING** that I don't know what potential damage this could cause to other elements of the site, perhaps someone with more experience with the DB could add some advice in this regard

Comment: Yes. That is the quick way (It was I did), but I think It isn't the right way. As you said, this change directly on DB could cause problems with other elements. But I didn't find a secure function to change it.